# Why does QTP need to be told twice to Stop?

Tags: qtp

In QuickTest Pro 10, I've noticed that whenever I have a Stop command in a function, QTP will ignore it. However, if I have a second Stop after the first command, QTP will stop on the second command. Why is this?

For example, let's say I have this in a function:

```
If True Then
    Stop
End If
```

...**won't** stop. However...

```
If True Then
    Stop
    Stop
End If
```

...**will** stop. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be the facts described in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/252895/en-us are responsible for the symptom?

I don't think, however, that it is a good idea to use `Stop` in QTP scripts, since QTP is one of the few  using the VBScript engine to implement its own IDE, and there are various integration issues between the debugger and the engine.

So I would not expect all VBS IDE features (and `Stop` is one of them) to be supported by QTP.

Comment: That Knowledge Base article does sound quite similar to the problem I have. Thing is, I've changed that registry key to '1' (to enable debugging) but it still doesn't work. It also says "if you are using WScript, you need to add the /d command line option to enable debugging. ". Does QTP use the WScript host and if so, where in QTP do I pass the /d option?

Comment: Even if there is not way to enable debugging, is there any similar command in QTP that will pause (not exit) the script? Something similar to breakpoints, but they have to be saved within the file itself and not re-added every time the script is opened.

Comment: It is not known how QTP integrates with VBS, but it surely does not spawn WScript.

Comment: Meanwhile, I am experiencing similar troubles: ExitTest exists the current test, ok. But most of the time (not always!) if the topmost test called the ExitTest caller using LoadAndAction, it does not exit, but continue after the LoadAndRunAction statement, performing the next LoadAndRunAction statement, but exiting from the called action after the first if statement (!). I´ll try to create a self-contained simple example for that, and will post it as a question. Very, very strange.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with using `Stop` to stop a test, are you looking for the `ExitTest` function used to stop QTP test runs?

Comment: I'm using stop as a break-point within the code. It's tremendously useful when coupling it with basic If/Thens. I often have an If/Then statement that detects weird behavior and have a `Stop` command if the If/Then test fails.
  
`Stop` only pauses the test and allows me to continue running after I check a few variables. So it's fairly different than using ExitTest.

Comment: @Eptin in that case, sorry I don't know.